# MoonAPNS (was:Run a PHP script from within ASP.Net/C#?)

Tags: c#, php, ios, web-services, apple-push-notifications

I have a PHP script (taken from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)) to send APNS notifications to an iOS app but the web services for the app are written in C#/ASP.Net.

I've managed to install PHP on the server and tested the script from the command line but don't know how to do this from within the web service (or even if this is possible).

Is there a way to run a PHP file from within ASP.Net or would I be better trying to re-write the PHP script in C#?

-EDIT-
Some more searching turned up [this](http://thinknook.com/execute-php-file-within-c-sharp-2011-12-10/), which prompted me to try the following code, without success:

```
public void PushNotificationAlert()
{
    string call = @"""php.exe""";
    string param1 = @"-f";
    string param2 = @"""~\APNS\myPush.php""";

    Process myProcess = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(call);
    myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", param1, param2);
    myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

    myProcess.Start();
    StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
}
```

Comment: There are already many C# APNS projects: https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp and the new and improved version: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp an other one: https://github.com/arashnorouzi/Moon-APNS

Comment: Thanks for the links. I had already had a go with [MoonAPNS](https://github.com/arashnorouzi/Moon-APNS) but kept getting certificate errors. I'll have a look at these two and see if I fare any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is still interested, this is the code I used with Moon that eventually worked:

```
// use MoonAPNS to send push notification
NotificationPayload payload = new NotificationPayload(deviceToken, message, badge, "default");
var notificationList = new List<NotificationPayload>() { payload };   
PushNotification push = new PushNotification(true, p12file, p12pass);
var result = push.SendToApple(notificationList);
```